# New Cordova project gives the error "BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'config.xml'"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I have just installed [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/dn841948) on my Visual Studio 2013 installation. I created a new Cordova project and I tried to compile it, and I got this error:

```
BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'config.xml'
```

I have it installed on another machine, and I haven't had that problem.

**EDIT:** I have confirmed that the file `config.xml` does exist.

**EDIT 2:** [Failed build log](http://pastebin.com/SmNmAyZw):

Comment: Have you tried to clear your Cordova cache from within Tools-> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Cordova Tools and then do a clean build?

Comment: @Avani - Just tried that. Did not resolve problem :(

Comment: Could you post your build output from when the build fails? Specifically, set the MSBuild verbosity to Diagnostic and then post your log.

Comment: Oh I see. I completely blanked out on the fact that the directory is basically a network share. Good catch! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD.exe doesn't work with UNC paths, which is why it defaults to the Windows directory since you have your Cordova project on a file system.

`'\\fs03\users\<redacted>\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1' (TaskId:31)
1>  CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. (TaskId:31)
1>  UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. (TaskId:31)`

Moving the project to a file system with a Drive letter should fix that for you.